# Scala cast to a variable type

Tags: scala, casting

I have the following code to cast **value** to the type of **default**:

```
def fct[T](value: Any, default: T): T = {
    val result = value.asInstanceOf[T]
    println(result, result.getClass.getName, result.isInstanceOf[T])
    result
}

val res = fct("foo", 42)
```

Which result is:

```
(foo,java.lang.String,true)
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(Test.sc2.tmp)
    at #worksheet#.res$lzycompute(Test.sc2.tmp:7)
    at #worksheet#.res(Test.sc2.tmp:7)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(Test.sc2.tmp:7)
```

Question is: why the println is displayed? The cast should fail. I tried to try / catch the 3 lines but no exception are raised during the function call.

Comment: That's weird. Note that I'm getting a result of `(Some(foo),scala.Some,true)` from your code.

Comment: Yes sorry i correct this

Comment: This is weird indeed. And I am getting `(foo,java.lang.String,true)` on Scala 2.11.8 console. The function body is somehow lazily executed. Which is strange.

Comment: I have tested on 2.10 and 2.11, same issue

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh No, there is no laziness involved.

Comment: Casting is a code smell in Scala. What are you trying to do that requires casting?

Comment: @KevinMeredith: this is a simple version of a function where value is like an Array[Any]. Sometimes i need a value from values, and sometime default and i would like to get an intercepted exception when value cannot be cast to default's type.

Comment: If you can, I suggest re-writing the function that returns a `Array[Any]`. `Any` is not a useful type in Scala since it's the top of the [class hierarchy](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types). Casting defeats the purpose of using the compiler to its fullest to reduce run-time errors, such as `asInstanceOf` can introduce.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because of type erasure, it's impossible to *actually* implement `value.{as/is}InstanceOf[T]` where `T` is a type parameter. Scala's designers decided it should still compile, but `value.asInstanceOf[T]` is actually a no-op (just like the equivalent `(T) value` in Java), while `value.isInstanceOf[T]` always returns `true` (in Java, `value instanceOf T` is a compiler error). (Since it never does what you want, I'd strongly like to see a warning instead, at least for `isInstanceOf`.)

But Scala allows to do what you want using [`ClassTag`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html):

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def fct[T](value: Any, default: T)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): T = {
    val result = (tag match {
      case ClassTag.Int => value.asInstanceOf[Int]
      ... same for other primitives
      case _ => tag.runtimeClass.cast(value)
    }).asInstanceOf[T]
    println(result, result.getClass.getName, tag.runtimeClass.isInstance(result))
    result
}
```

(You still need `asInstanceOf[T]` because `tag.runtimeClass` *usually* returns the same class `T` represents but not always, so its static return type has to be `Class[_]` and `cast` returns `Any`).

However, pattern-matching `: T` handles presence of a `ClassTag` automatically and already handles boxing, so

```
def fct[T](value: Any, default: T)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): T = value match {
    case result: T => result
    case _ => default // or whatever you want to do if value is not a T
}
```

is the better way to do this.

Comment: This is called enlightenment.

Comment: Damn, I want to be you when I grow up 

Comment: It does not compile: Error:(6, 4) type mismatch;
 found   : result.type (with underlying type Any)
 required: T
  result
  ^

Comment: @Benjamin Sorry, fixed.

Comment: @Alexey Almost: it compiles but fct(123, 42) => java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to int

Comment: @Benjamin Ah, that's because of boxing. I don't think there is any simple way to do it without matching `ClassTag.Int`, etc. specifically.

Comment: Ho ok. I'll try this. Good job

Comment: `... while value.isInstanceOf[T] always returns true`. But, `def f[A](x: A): Boolean = x.isInstanceOf[Int]` returns `false` for `f("foo")`. Could you please explain more?

Comment: @KevinMeredith "where `T` is a type parameter". `Int` here is not a type parameter.