# Performing an explicit cast based on `Class` instance

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

Assume there is a class `X`. At some point in my code, I get an `o` of type `Object` and I want to explicitly cast it to `X`. Normally, I would do `val x: X = o.asInstanceOf[X]`. However, `X` is not in scope, all I have is `X`'s instance of `Class`, like so:

1. I pass `classOf[X]` to my function as an argument called `classOfX`.
2. Within my function, I would like to do `val x: X = o.asInstanceOf[classOfX]`.

Is there a way to do this in Scala?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220804/scala-cast-to-a-variable-type

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The function in the post you linked is generic, mine is not. As described above, there is no generic type argument `X`, but an argument of type `Class` called `classOfX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only kind of. `java.lang.Class` has a `cast` method that lets you cast a `Class[A]` to an `A`. You could write a method like this:

```
def cast[A](o: Any, clazz: Class[A]): A = clazz.cast(o)

scala> cast("abc", classOf[String])
res10: String = abc
```

This will "work" for most classes, but not for Scala boxed primitives:

```
scala> cast(1, classOf[Int])
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to int
```

And of course, casting only works modulo type erasure, so this will not immediately throw an exception:

```
scala> val a = List("a").getClass
a: Class[_ <: List[String]] = class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon

scala> cast(List(1), a)
res16: List[String] = List(1)
```

On the upside, it will also work with classes obtained at run time using `getClass`, like above.

The downside is that you should be avoiding casting at all costs, because of how error prone it will make the code. It throws type safety out the window. Rarely should anyone find themselves in a situation where they have an object where they don't know what it is, but can somehow tell the compiler what it is using `classOf`. It is likely that using some form of generics could eliminate a casting problem, but it is impossible to tell without more code.